# Basics with Ramda/Functional Programming

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js

## The Part That Works

I've read a bunch of the articles and watched a few of the talk about FP in JavaScript and decided to give it a go.

I get that this is basic stuff, but one more time? Here goes:

```js
const easy = [
  0,0,4,6,7,2,0,0,0,
  5,0,0,8,0,0,0,9,6,
  0,6,3,0,4,0,0,0,8,
  3,8,2,1,0,0,9,6,0,
  4,7,5,0,0,0,1,0,0,
  9,1,0,2,0,4,5,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,9,
  0,0,1,0,0,0,7,4,3,
  2,0,0,0,6,3,8,0,1
];

const expandSudoku = R.map(
  R.ifElse(
    R.equals(0),
    R.always(R.range(1,10));
    R.of
  )
);

console.log(expandSudoku(easy));
```

This takes an array of numbers and maps it into an array of arrays.

- 0 -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
- n -> [n]

### R.equals Confuses Me

So correct me if I'm wrong, but this is effectively the same thing (With some anonymous wrapper functions):

```js
const easy = [
  0,0,4,6,7,2,0,0,0,
  5,0,0,8,0,0,0,9,6,
  0,6,3,0,4,0,0,0,8,
  3,8,2,1,0,0,9,6,0,
  4,7,5,0,0,0,1,0,0,
  9,1,0,2,0,4,5,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,9,
  0,0,1,0,0,0,7,4,3,
  2,0,0,0,6,3,8,0,1
];

const expandSudoku = R.map(v =>
  R.ifElse(
    x => R.equals(0)(x),
    x => R.range(1,10),
    x => R.of(x)
  )(v)
);

console.log(expandSudoku(easy));
```

First question: why do I get an error if I change `R.equals(0)(x)` to `R.equals(0, x)`? I thought with Ramda's style of currying, those should be the same. Is this just a typescript thing? The compiled JavaScript runs just fine.

> **The Error:** Argument of type '(x: any) => (a: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pred'.

---

#### Passing through the second parameter?

I have this helper function:

`const pass2nd = R.curry((fn, arg1, arg2) => fn(arg2));`

Which I've used like this:

```js
const indexToCoord = R.applySpec({
  x: R.modulo(R.__,9), 
  y: R.compose(Math.floor, R.divide(R.__,9))
});
const makeCell = R.applySpec({
  coord: pass2nd(indexToCoord), // pass2nd to only get the second argument
  options: R.unary(R.ifElse(    // Unary to only get the first argument
    R.equals(0),
    R.always(R.range(1,10)),
    R.of
  ))
});
const mapIndexed = R.addIndex(R.map);
const expandSudoku = mapIndexed(makeCell);

console.log(expandSudoku(easy));
```

Does Ramda come with something similar? Is that a code-smell? What's up?

#### Finally:

When is composition too much? Is

```js
const indexToCoord = R.applySpec({
  x: R.modulo(R.__,9), 
  y: R.compose(Math.floor, R.divide(R.__,9))
});
```

generally preferable to

```js
const indexToCoord = v => ({
  x: v % 9,
  y: Math.floor(v/9)
});
```

?

Comment: One question per question post, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First question: why do I get an error if I change `R.equals(0)(x)` to `R.equals(0, x)`? I thought with Ramda's style of currying, those should be the same. Is this just a typescript thing? The compiled JavaScript runs just fine.

They should be the same and if the JS runs fine, then it's definitely a TS question.  I'm afraid I don't know enough about TS to tell you how to fix it though.

> I  have this helper function:
>
> ```js
> const pass2nd = R.curry((fn, arg1, arg2) => fn(arg2));
> ```
>
> [ ... ] Does Ramda come with something similar? Is that a code-smell? What's up?

You can use [`nthArg`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#nthArg) in a similar manner.  But I tend to feel that if I have to reach for that, then I'm trying to hard to make points-free something that doesn't need to be.  (Similarly with [`useWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) and a few other Ramda functions.)

> When is composition too much? Is
>
> ```js
> const indexToCoord = R.applySpec({
>   x: R.modulo(R.__,9), 
>   y: R.compose(Math.floor, R.divide(R.__,9))
> });
> ```
>
> generally preferable to
>
> ```js
> const indexToCoord = v => ({
>   x: v % 9,
>   y: Math.floor(v/9)
> });
> ```
>
> ?

I'd say very much the reverse.  Your second function is quite readable.  The only important reason to go to a points-free style, in my opinion, is to make the code more readable.  This does not do so, and I wouldn't bother.

---

One additional caution.  In this:

```js
const expandSudoku = R.map(
  R.ifElse(
    R.equals(0),
    R.always(R.range(1,10)),
    R.of
  )
)
```

the use of `always` might be problematic.  That depends upon how you are using the results.  But a lot of sudoku systems use a fair bit of mutation in order to simplify what's needed for performance.  If you are doing so, you should know that `always` simply returns the cached value supplied.  It's not a clone.  And if you use it this way and you choose to mutate the resulting array, you will mutate it for every `0` you replace.

If that's a concern, [`thunkify`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#thunkify) might make a better choice:

```js
const expandSudoku = R.map(
  R.ifElse(
    R.equals(0),
    R.thunkify (R.range) (1, 10),
    R.of
  )
)
```

Basically `thunkify (fn) (...args)` yields the equivalent of `() => fn (...args)`.  This is much safer than `always` in the presence of mutation.

Of course if you are doing everything immutably, then congratulations!  And I'd love to see the result.